# Wrong message for duplicates

Tags: bug, closed-questions, close-reasons

The message for a duplicate question is wrong:

> This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question.

The correct action is of course **improving the current question, not asking a new one**. The misleading recommendation to ask the question again is completely wrong.

We moderators cannot edit that text, so it has to be fixed by someone else. :)

Comment: nice catch.....

Comment: Some of our users stepped into that trap already. I was wondering why, that’s how I found it. I don’t read those messages usually. :)

Comment: Not so sure about it. On Stackoverflow we have the same close reason so it's perhaps useful to take a look on meta there, too. Please take a look here: [Duplicate explanation should encourage improvement of original](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166525/duplicate-explanation-should-encourage-improvement-of-original) - the answer suggests the OP sees a message that invites her to edit instead of asking a new one.

Answer (score 1):

I think this doesn't even go far enough:

> This question has been asked before and already has an answer

From our experience with users who ask the same question again and again, I suggest something near to this:

> This question has been asked before. If it has been asked **by you**, then please don't ask a new one, but improve your existing one. If the question has been asked by someone else and doesn't meet your needs, then go on and ask a new one.

I know it's not perfect, just a hint to take that into consideration as well.

Comment: This is wrong. Most duplicates are asked by other users. The text should explain how to improve this closed question.

Comment: @toscho Not wrong. [Like this one from just now](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/109171/how-to-keep-next-and-previous-buttons-above-the-big-image-using-nggallery-carous). Happens often enough that _I_ think it should as well be part of the notice.

Comment: If someone duplicates her/his own question, we can leave a comment and delete that question.

Comment: Well, it wasn't deleted, but marked as duplicate :)

Comment: Tempted to flag this as duplicate just for fun